# What was the origin of the famous movie quote "all out of bubble gum"?

Tags: history-of, john-carpenter, they-live

In John Carpenter's [*They Live*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live) we hear the famous line

> I have come here to chew bubble gum and kick ass, and I'm all outta bubble gum.

It obviously made it into the general vernacular, but was it ad-libbed by Mr. Piper as some suggest, or did it originate elsewhere?

Comment: I'm here to kick ass and take names. And I'm all out of... names.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that this was older than its use Duke Nukem.

Comment: We have a reasonable earliest estimate; invention of bubble gum is credited as 1928 by Walter Diemer while working at a chewing gum factory. It’s likely that no quote specifically using “bubble gum” could exist prior to existence of bubble gum.

Comment: I still think Duke Nukem delivered it best.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When asked this directly, Roddy Piper said that he ad-libbed it.

From a 2013 [interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20190831133511/https://my.xfinity.com/blogs/movies/2013/07/17/%E2%80%98rowdy%E2%80%99-roddy-piper-stocked-up-on-bubble-gum-reflects-on-%E2%80%98they-live%E2%80%99/):

> Onda: Did you really ad-lib that line?
>
> Piper: Yeah. I couldn’t tell you what it really means either. It was one of those – “Roddy, you’ve got bullets on you, you’ve got a shotgun, you’ve got sunglasses, you go into a bank, you’re not gonna rob it, say something … action!” I’m all out of bubblegum. Lunch! That was it. No more than that. I know, it’s crazy.

Comment: Nice! Thx, one of my absolute favorites, ranks right up there with `I'll be back`

Answer (score 22):

*Five on the Black Hand Side* (1973), 15 years before *They Live* (1988). Timestamp 1:49 in this clip.

> I ain’t giving up nothing but bubblegum and hard times, and I’m fresh out of bubblegum.

Not saying this is the original, or that Piper actually had a line. All I'm saying is that this was a saying before *They Live*.

Comment: nice - and now I know where a line from "Rapper's Delight" comes from as well

Comment: That 'rap' predates this film by at least three years, back to 1970 and possibly earlier; https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Die_Nigger_Die/GqEKAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22fresh%20out%20of%20bubble%20gum%22